# Swift textfield automatic cursor

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Is it possible to put a cursor automatically in the first of textfields, when opening a screen?
For example, when I open a screen with Email and Password, I want to right after that type my email, without pressing a textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chose whichever textfield you want to become first responder:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()

  emailTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

}
```

Comment: What if I have no variables/outlets, only tableView with two cells, one for email and one for password?

Comment: You must be able to reference them somehow? => IBOutlets

Comment: I did it in cellForRowAt indexPath. It was easy. I will still accept @Mumtaz's answer because I didn't specify everything in my question.

Comment: you should not call that in cellForRowAtIndexPath, otherwise every time you scroll pass that cell, you would show the keyboard

Comment: @javierrivarola there is no scrolling , only 2 cells on the screen. But what is your advice anyway?

Comment: you should call it on `viewDidAppear` , get the visible cell you want to show the keyboard, get the reference to the textField, and becomeFirstResponder

Answer (score 2):

If you have a static tableView, just take an `IBOutlet` from your textFields, and in the method `viewWillAppear` you can call to `yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`

If you have a dynamic tableView, you have some kind of data source object, you can loop in it, find the index of the first textField, then you have to scroll the tableView to that cell, so it becomes visible, and then you should get a reference to the cell with `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPathOfYourCell) as? YourCustomTextCell`, and then you can do something like `cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()`

Answer (score 1):

Create an **IBOutlet** of TextFiled in ViewController and in `viewDidLoad()` method call `myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```